# Создание пользователей БД

Tags: c#, sql-server

Как осуществить программно (с помощью ролей) следующие действия:

1. У меня 2 типа пользователей- преподаватели и студенты. Преподаватели могут изменять, удалять, добавлять записи. Студенты - только читать то, что можно их группе (студенческие группы, типа ПИ-10, В-31). Как лучше? создать для каждой группы отдельную роль или одну роль всем студентам? Необходимо учесть тот факт, что файлы, созданные преподавателями, будут доступны не всем группам студентов.
2. Какие роли баз данных давать преподавателям и студентам?
3. Как студенты будут подключаться под своими ролями? (хотелось бы пример строки подключения).
4. Каким образом можно осуществить разграничение доступа к ресурсам с помощью этих ролей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вопроса не ясно что является клиентом: десктоповое приложение или веб-приложение?
Вообще всё это самым быстрым способом можно решить именно на ролях и форменной  аутентификации Windows. Правда для этого не в коем случае не можно использовать .Net Framework XXX Client Profile, поскольку понадобится заюзать System.Web.

Для понимания, что надо сделать, нужно изучить вопрос с Membership ([изучить надо тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tw292whz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).
Потом создать быстренько для отладки маленький локальный вебпроектик, создать (как описано у майкрософта) базу и таблицы и протестировать всё это. Как заработает, упаковать весь нужный функционал в библиотеку. И забыть на веки-вечные как страшный сон (дальше просто пользоваться только этой библиотекой).

Если же это десктопое приложение, то в app.config нужно перенести секции из web.config-а, добавить в референсы отсуствующие библиотеки, одну я уже назвал, и вперёд - рисуйте логин форму и прочее.

Если проект серьёзный, а не учителя/ученики :), то желательно не наглеть с app.config, а придумать как себя обезопасить, разместив его внутри ресурсов (сделав embedded), но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваша информация, несомненно, важна для меня. Но мне хотелось бы получить ответы, а после прочтения вашего поста у меня появилось еще больше вопросов)
Приложение будет десктоповым.

Comment: но для того, чтобы получить ответ надо задать правильный вопрос.
на общий вопрос, Вы получили вполне конкретный с явками и паролями общий ответ.
Для решения вашей задачи надо знать, что именно и на каких условиях делается. К примеру, какую БД можно использовать? Может у Вас удалённый SQL сервер, а может какой-нибудь SQLite или MySQL, может быть Вы в качестве носителя "всех благ" MS Access будете использовать. Откуда мне всё это было знать, чтобы отвечать на вопрос?